# Krull dimension of valuation rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

It is mentioned in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring#cite_ref-7) that one cay show that the Krull dimension of a valuation ring $D$ is equal to the cardinality of the set of proper subrings of the fraction field $K$ containing $D$.

Moreover, it is also claimed that there is a bijective correspondence between $\operatorname{Spec}(D)$ and the set of all subrings in $K$ containing $D$. I can step by step follow the proof (mentioned in Wiki) but I do not have a good understanding why it is true. Is there any excellent explanation?

Comment: The main observation is that the ideals of a valuation ring are totally ordered. From here it essentially follows that one may obtain the fraction field of $D$ by inverting away from larger and larger primes, which correspond to subrings (localizations of $D$) of the fraction field containing $D$. This correspondence between primes and subrings of $K$ gives us the result about Krull dimension